Mapping subdomain to subfolder (WordPress)?
I have 3 WordPress websites installed in three differents subdomains : site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com, site3.domain.com.
In order to manage the new websites (I redesigning them) at one place only, I've installed a Multisite with the subfolder option (in order to keep the old sites live while redesigning the sites).
So the new websites are at domain.com/site1 and so on...
Now, I'm trying to figure out how to put those new sites live, but with the old domains?
The thing is that only one of the three sites is ready and must be put live. So, I cannot switch the WP mulsite option to subdomain. Is there a way to map domain.com/site1 to site1.domain.com?
I've looked at plugins, but all the WP documentation says that it has now a built-in fonction for mapping. Seems to be easy to map to a new domain (domain.com/site1 -> newdomain.com), but nothing seems to work a subfolder/subdomain?
